# Como utilizar el evento Click dentro de un fragment en xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Estoy tratando de iniciar una actividad o un layout desde un fragment. Estoy utilizando un ImageButton. Encontré un código pero el evento SetOnClickListener no funciona.

También no se que código iría en el MainActivity.

[image: El codigo que tengo]

Comment: Hola Elias, recuerda que es importante agregar el código como texto ya que de esta forma aseguras que sea visible para todos los miembros de la comunidad, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes revisar la [documentaciòn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/buttons/custom-button) , este es un ejemplo, tienes un layout donde se encuentra definido el botòn:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/android_button" />
```

obtienes la referencia del botón dentro del layout:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
```

y asignas el listener de esta forma:

```
button.Click += (o, e) => {
    Toast.MakeText (this, "Beep Boop", ToastLength.Short).Show();
};
```

---

De acuerdo a tu código serìa :

```
BTNjugador.Click += (o, e) => {
    Toast.MakeText (this, "Elias, has dado clic al boton!", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
};
```

Comment: En mi caso que quiero iniciar un actividad desde el fragmento, La estoy iniciando con el intent pero el getActivity() no funciona

Comment: Te recomiendo implementar la interfaz de onClick listener. Hay que tener cuidado cuando se delegan eventos. Este tipo de implementación utiliza suscripciones, es decir cuando haces `+=` estás suscribiendo un evento. Recuerda que Android maneja ciclo de vida y si se repite una suscripción el evento se disparará múltiples veces. Recomienda implementar la interfaz o eliminar la suscripción de un evento con `-=` antes de suscribir uno nuevo. No digo que suceda en este escenario pero si se acostumbra a hacerlo así tendrá problemas en su aplicación.

Comment: Desde fragmento usa `this.Activity`, @EliasQuintanilla